# "I have seen people saying ..." vs "I have seen people say..."; What is the difference?

Tags: past-simple, past-continuous

I have heard people using both versions at times but I don't quite get the difference. I am not used to the second version and a little in doubt if it is even grammatically correct. Can you also give me some references to study the second template in more depth?

Comment: You can't see sounds.

Comment: Perhaps a lip-reader could see people saying things?

Comment: @codi6 Have you heard of synesthesia?

Comment: @CoderInNetwork Lol fair enough, some people can see sounds. But the English language doesn't really take that into account when creating grammatical structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, “saying” has the effect of putting you right there in the moment of the person speaking, whereas “say” is a bit more past tense, and focuses simply on the fact that “they said that.” With “saying”, you begin to picture the speaker in your mind during their actual act of speaking, whereas with “say” you focus more simply on the fact that something has been said.

While it is true that we cannot see sounds, the use of “seen” may emphasise the fact that we were there in person to witness them speaking, or as Michael Harvey comments, it may refer to lip reading. With that said, “heard” would probably be more common than “seen”.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense.